# BinaryFileResponse sent via AppCache not working

Tags: php, caching, symfony

I generate multiple images with PHP and now want to cache them via Symfony's built-in HttpCache, but somehow I get no response when sending BinaryFileResponses. It works for the first time after flushing the cache, but after that I only get a response with HTTP status 200 and no size (according to Safari's web developer tools).

In my web/app.php I have the following code:

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
$kernel = new AppCache($kernel);
```

The controller looks as follows:

```
$response = new BinaryFileResponse($file->getPathname());
$response->trustXSendfileTypeHeader();
$response->setMaxAge(3600 * 336);
$response->setSharedMaxAge(3600 * 336);
```

Normal responses like HTML work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a bug not yet solved as of today.

[HttpCache stores metadata but not content for BinaryFileResponse which causes cache hits with no content. #9128](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/9128)